# How to find out unknown number of rows and cols in a input file?

Tags: c++, file-io, multidimensional-array

Okay so the input file looks like this:

```
00000000100000001010 
00000000010000001001
11100000010100000010 
10100100101010101010 
00101010010010101000
```

This is an example grid which is 5x20 and the catch is that the rows and cols can be arbitrary. Which means that I need to figure out how many rows and cols the input file has before I can start computing my two dimensional array.

So I am a little confused because right now I am just trying to read in the array then output it to the console without knowing the rows and cols initially. Please help me with this it's annoying and I can't find a way to do it.

**P.S. I can not use the string library**

Comment: Read each line into a `std::string` and push it back into `std::vector<std::string>>`. Printing will be easy, and you'll be able to get the size throw `size()` method.

Comment: That doesn't use the <string> library right? Because I can't use that

Comment: So... this is homework?

Comment: Well yes, this is just a tiny part, its way more complicated. I have to make the game of life lol

Comment: You can't `#include <string>`? Are you given a specific list of which ones you can or can't use? You have to use some libraries, I highly doubt you're being asked to do any I/O (file or console) without a library.

Comment: @jerry yeah <string> is the only library I can't use, I can use all others

Comment: I guess I would advise initializing an array with a predefined size, walking through the array character by character until you reach `\n`. If the amount of characters read is `>=` to the number of characters the array can hold, resize the array. Repeat for the following lines until you reach the end-of-file.

Comment: @MattRay Understood. Be aware that `fstream` includes `string`, though I don't think that's really what your teacher meant.

Answer (score 0):

The traditional way to do this is to loop through each character in a char array and keeping track of the number of characters until you hit a newline, depending on the format of the data.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char arr[] = "00000000100000001010\n00000000010000001001\n11100000010100000010\n10100100101010101010 \n00101010010010101000";
    int cols = 0;
    int rows = 0;

    for(int i = 0; arr[i] != '\0';i++)
    {
        if(rows == 0)
            cols++;
        if(arr[i] == '\n')
            rows++;
    }
    std::cout<<cols<<" Colums"<<std::endl<<rows+1<<" Rows"<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This is assuming that the columns are uniform and you have your data in an array.

It's much easier/cleaner/better to read in character by character from a stream, but this is the old way.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to proceed, depending on what the motivation was behind your teacher's prohibition on using `string`. One of the two options below will probably be acceptable. Note that I've played a little fast and loose and skipped a fair amount of error checking, but you shouldn't when you flesh it out. In all cases, I'm assuming the file does not end in a line terminator (as you've shown) and is rectangular (same number of characters on every line).

### Use an automatically resizing container

You can still get the essential benefit (for this case) of free memory management without using a `string`. For example, push the characters one-by-one into a `vector`:

```
std::ifstream inF("input.txt");
std::vector<char> contents;
char c;

while(inF.get(c).good())
{
    contents.push_back(c);
}

int rows = 1 + std::count(contents.begin(), contents.end(), '\n');
int columns = std::find(contents.begin(), contents.end(), '\n') - contents.begin();
```

### Read out the length of the file from the stream

It's a pretty simple matter to figure out how big the file is and pre-allocate a buffer large enough to hold it:

```
std::ifstream inF("input.txt");

// option 1
inF.seekg(0, std::ios_base::end);
int charCount = inF.tellg();

// option 2
//int charCount = 0;
//while(inF.get() != std::char_traits<char>::eof())
//{
//    charCount++;
//}
//inF.clear();

char* contents = new char[charCount + 1];

inF.seekg(0);
inF.read(contents, charCount);

contents[charCount] = '\0';

int rows = 1 + std::count(contents, contents + charCount, '\n');
int columns = std::find(contents, contents + charCount, '\n') - contents;

delete[] contents;
```