# Simplest way to count the rows and columns in a matrix

Tags: c, dynamic, file-io, multidimensional-array

Okay so I am making the game of life in C not C++ because we are not allowed to use the string library and I was just wondering how to count the rows and columns of an arbitrary input file..

And yes this is a homework assignment but this is just the very beginning.. and I am stuck and feel like an idiot.

Here's an example:

```
00000000100000001010
00000000010000001001
11100000010100000010
10100100101010101010
00101010010010101000
```

So I need a SIMPLE way to count the rows and columns in an arbitrary file, I guess you would count char by char for columns and line by line for rows but every time I try something like that it just messes up.

So please help me out on this, thanks!

Comment: @RikayanBandyopadhyay honestly just don't know how to really do it without using strings..

Comment: @MattRay You've posted essentially the same question twice before and even [accepted one of the answers](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22002263/1270168). What's wrong with the previous answers that do not use `string` ([shameless plug : )](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21940718/1270168) )? What is it that you don't understand or need help with?

Comment: Oh wow, I don't know how I didn't see that.. I'm sorry. I just implemented his from the other question and it works fine.. my bad @jerry

Comment: @MattRay Sorry, I completely misread your first line and missed the fact that this question is tagged C. Both linked answers are C++ (as the questions are tagged that way). Therefore, this is not really a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

you need to do it in c right. ok first count the number of characters in each line by using somemethod. let len1 be the line length. then use

```
fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
len2 = ftell(fp);
```

then len2=len2/(len1+1). add 1 to len1 to consider the newline character at the end of each line and EOF at the last line. then the matrix size is (len1,len2)

Comment: Note that the end-of-line character may actually be two characters (on Windows systems) so you'd like to account for that. Also, it assumes a file with no extra whitespaces at all.

Comment: @ysap ok.then for windows need to change calculations to len2=(len2-1)/(len1+1) if EOF is 2 bytes.

Comment: Actually, it is EOL, not EOF that is 2 bytes, so probably `len2/(len1-2)`. This also assumes a newline at the end of the last line, of-course.

Comment: @ysap ya my reading mistake. ya it should be len2=(len2+1)/(len1) with EOF at last line and (len2-1)/len1 with newline at lastline.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work

```
char *matrix; // this is our matrix read in from file

int rows = 0;
int cols = 0;
int tempCols = 0;
int index = 0;

// assumes matrix is a null-terminated string
while (matrix[index] != 0) {
    tempCols++;
    if (matrix[index] == '\n') {
        rows++;
        if (tempCols > cols) {
            // this will return the largest column size if it's not rectangular
            cols = tempCols;
            tempCols = 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    FILE *fp;
    int row = 0, col = 0;
    char c;
    fp = fopen("file","r+");
    while( (c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF ){
        if(c != '\n' && row == 0){
            col++;
        }
        else if(c == '\n')
            row++;
    }
    row++;  /* If your file doesn't end with a \n */
    printf("Rows = %d\tColumns = %d\n",row,col);
    return 0;
}
```

Here "file" is your name of the arbitrary input file.
**Caution**: This code works correctly only when there is no "enter" at the end of file.